# What JSON Format when using CQL fromJson function?

Tags: json, cassandra, cql

I'm playing around with Cassandra's CQL fromJson function and have the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO promotions.promotion (id, siteid, clientid, type, name, code, description, created, 
duestart, dueend, status, resolution, typespec, currencies
) 
VALUES (
    uuid(), 100000, 100000, 'FS', 'One', 'ONE', 'One description', 
    dateof(now()), dateof(now()), dateof(now()), 'WAITING', 'UNRESOLVED', { 'spins':'10' },
    fromJson('{
        "currencyId" : "123",
        "currencyCode" : "GBP",
        "currencyGames" : [{
            "gameConfigId" : 123,
            "typeSpec" : { "numSpins" : 10, "dummy" : "yes" }
        }]           
    }')
);
```

When I run this in DevCenter or cqlsh I get the following error:

[image]

I a bit of a beginner with Cassandra and am just learning its potential, but this has me stumped. I've tried different combinations of brackets, but to no avail. I must be doing something stupid.

The schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE promotions.promotion_currency_game (
    gameConfigId bigint,
    typeSpec MAP<text,text>
);

CREATE TYPE promotions.promotion_currency (
    currencyId bigint,
    currencyCode text,
    currencyGames set<FROZEN<promotion_currency_game>>
);

CREATE TABLE promotions.promotion (
    id uuid,
    siteid bigint,
    clientid bigint,
    type text,
    name text,
    code text,
    description text,
    created timestamp,
    duestart timestamp,
    dueend timestamp,
    status text,
    resolution text,
    typespec MAP<text,text>,
    currencies SET<FROZEN<promotion_currency>>, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH compression = {
    'class' : 'LZ4Compressor',
    'enabled' : true
};
```

Comment: can you include the schema definition for table promotions.promotion?

Comment: At work now, but when I get home, I'll post it up.

Comment: @Kango_V could you post this schema?

Comment: Added the schema. Sorry for delay. Annoying when Christmas gets in the way of my programming ;)